# Override Downshift ID

Tags: reactjs, downshift

I'm trying to override the default ids that Downshift provides.

I tried passing the id through `getInputProps()` like the docs suggest but it did not work.

```
{...getInputProps({ inputId: 'my-input-id' })}
```

Passing the id directly to the input did not work as well.

```
<input id='my-input-id />
```

In both cases, the id remains `downshift-0-input`. Any ideas on how I can override this id?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you're doing `inputId: 'my-input-id'` instead of `id: 'my-input-id'`...

Comment: Documentation mentions this, adding `inputId: 'my-input-id'` sets id to the input
https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift#inputid

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the documentation is wrong. However the TypeScript types are correct and I just tested and simply passing `id` works:

```js
{...getInputProps({ id: 'my-input-id' })}
```